# Websocket not working in react, when storing its value in react context

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-context

I want to open websocket connection when user clicks on login button.
What i am doing ,  in **app.js** i am creating websocket and save it in a react context.
Then in **login.js** , getting socket value from react context and when user clicks on login button , try to open the connection, but its not working.
If i tried opening the connection in app.js without saving it in context then code working fine.

**App.js :-**

```js
import SocketContext from './shared/socketContext.js';

const socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");


class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}> // passing the value of socket in react context
          <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
          <Redirect to='/login' />
          </SocketContext.Provider>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

**Login.js :-**

```js
   componentDidMount(){
        this.inputRef.current.focus();
        console.log(this.props.userDetails);
        console.log(this.props.socket); 
//getting the socket value on console when component did mount.
    }
```

```js
        componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.userDetails !== ''){
            console.log(`user name is ${this.props.userDetails}`)
            this.openSocketConnection() //opening the connection once userdetails have some value.
        }
    }

    openSocketConnection(){
        const a = this.props.socket ;
        a.addEventListener('open',()=>{
            console.log('Connection has established')
            // this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        })
        this.props.socket.addEventListener('message',(event)=>{
            alert(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
          });
    }
```

Comment: `static contextType = SocketContext` and then use `const socket= this.context` in a componentDidMount.
If you are using functional components try using `const socket = React.useContext(SocketContext)` to get your context.
There is a good article on the subject here: https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/

Comment: Thankyou Johas, Its working using static contextType and then use const socket= this.context in a componentDidMount. But not working when i use it in componentDitUpdate. I wanted to open the websocket connection in componentDidUpdate. Do you know, how can i achieve that?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with componentDidUpdate since I do 100% hooks now. But I guess you can declare it in componentDidMount and perhaps store it in this.state and then use this.state.socket in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: No, its not working, if i stored it in state. Now i have implemented singleton class for websocket and its working.